How to setup Ubuntu as a mobile WiFi router with NAT - connect to a WiFi provider, NAT to Ethernet port?
Here are what I have:

a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04, with a wifi and an ethernet port.
a ZyXEL mobile WiFi router that uses an Ethernet port.

My family will go on a cruise trip, where WiFi costs will be significant if multiple devices need to subscribe to the ship's Wifi service.
So I would like to setup the Ubuntu laptop as a router that connects to the cruise's Wifi service, and setup NAT on the Ethernet interface. The ZyXEL mobile router then connects to this Ethernet port and the rest of devices connect to this router. This way, we just need to purchase one WiFi connection.
NAT is needed as I was told that some cruise may block multiple devices from accessing the same subscribed Wifi connection via a private WiFi hotspot. So I will have to hide the individual devices' MAC from the service provider, i.e., all outgoing traffic will need to carry only the MAC of the laptop's WiFi interface.
Would an expert please share how this can be done?
Thanks for sharing your insight!

You have a tag for Ubuntu Touch this is not a supported version of Ubuntu on this site and there is no mention of this in the question. Please correct.

In general if you share your Internet by creating a a hotspot using Ubuntu. It will automatically set up NAT and a different range of IP addresses for the hotspot. In any case, the mobile router will also create a NAT. None of the NAT may prevent the cruise ship guys to come after you. Your WiFi hotspot will be easily detectable as it will broadcast its signal all around your cabin. All this has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

This question is similar to: Share wireless Internet connection through ethernet. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for the insight. Will check out this link. As for the router, I can configure it not to broadcast SSID. But then it seems the question becomes: will the MAC address of individual devices still be contained in the packet header of outbound traffic?
